# Group/Count list of dictionaries based on value

Tags: python, list, aggregate-functions

I've got a list of Tokens which looks something like:

```
[{
    Value: "Blah",
    StartOffset: 0,
    EndOffset: 4
}, ... ]
```

What I want to do is get a count of how many times each value occurs in the list of tokens.

In VB.Net I'd do something like...

```
Tokens = Tokens.
GroupBy(Function(x) x.Value).
Select(Function(g) New With {
           .Value = g.Key,
           .Count = g.Count})
```

What's the equivalent in Python?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> tokens = [{"Value": "Blah", "SO": 0}, {"Value": "zoom", "SO": 5}, {"Value": "Blah", "SO": 2}, {"Value": "Blah", "SO": 3}]
>>> Counter(tok['Value'] for tok in tokens)
Counter({'Blah': 3, 'zoom': 1})
```

if you only need a count.  If you want them grouped by the value, you could use `itertools.groupby` and something like:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> def keyfn(x):
        return x['Value']
... 
>>> [(k, list(g)) for k,g in groupby(sorted(tokens, key=keyfn), keyfn)]
[('Blah', [{'SO': 0, 'Value': 'Blah'}, {'SO': 2, 'Value': 'Blah'}, {'SO': 3, 'Value': 'Blah'}]), ('zoom', [{'SO': 5, 'Value': 'zoom'}])]
```

although it's a little trickier because `groupby` requires the grouped terms to be contiguous, and so you have to sort by the key first.

Answer (score 7):

Let's assume that is your python list, containing dictionnaries:

```
my_list = [{'Value': 'Blah',
            'StartOffset': 0,
            'EndOffset': 4},
           {'Value': 'oqwij',
            'StartOffset': 13,
            'EndOffset': 98},
           {'Value': 'Blah',
            'StartOffset': 6,
            'EndOffset': 18}]
```

A one liner:

```
len([i for i in a if i['Value'] == 'Blah']) # returns 2
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import collections

# example token list
tokens = [{'Value':'Blah', 'Start':0}, {'Value':'BlahBlah'}]

count=collections.Counter([d['Value'] for d in tokens])
print count
```

shows

```
Counter({'BlahBlah': 1, 'Blah': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
token = [{
    'Value': "Blah",
    'StartOffset': 0,
    'EndOffset': 4
}, ... ]

value_counter = {}

for t in token:
    v = t['Value']
    if v not in value_counter:
        value_counter[v] = 0
    value_counter[v] += 1

print value_counter
```

Answer (score 0):

Another efficient way is to convert data to Pandas DataFrame and then aggregate them. Like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.groupby('key')['value'].count()
df.groupby('key')['value'].sum()
```