# Python count same keys in ordered dict

Tags: python

I have multiple ordered dict (in this example 3, but can be more) as a result from an API, with same key value pairs and I test for the same key, then I print out another key's value:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = [OrderedDict([('type', 'a1'), ('rel', 'asd1')]),
     OrderedDict([('type', 'a1'), ('rel', 'fdfd')]),
     OrderedDict([('type', 'b1'), ('rel', 'dfdff')])]

for item in d:
    if item["type"] == "a1":
        print(item["rel"])
```

This works fine, but it could happen that the return from API can be different, because there is only 1 result. Without the [ at the begining and ] at the end, like this:

```
d = OrderedDict([('type', 'b1'), ('rel', 'dfdff')])
```

In this case, I will receive this error:

```
    if item["type"] == "a1":
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

So I would like to test also (maybe in the same if it is possible) if the key "type" has more then 0 value with "a1" then print the items or to test the OrderedDict have the square brackets at the begining or at the end.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If there are no dicts with the key type as "a1", nothing will be printed...

Comment: Also is `OrderedDict` really relevant to the question?

Comment: [Group/Count list of dictionaries based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15815976/6045800)

Comment: You are right, sorry for missleading, I modified my question then I think it is clear now.

Comment: I don't understand. You get the error because you treat your input (`d`) as a list of dicts, but it is actually a dict. Then you say you want to check *"if the key "type" has more then 0 value with "a1""*. What you really want to check is whether `d` is a list or a dict?

Comment: Exactly. Now I realized the API answers, this would be the best.

Comment: [What's the canonical way to check for type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/152580/6045800)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "square brackets" represent a list object.  You simply need to check if `d` is a `list` or an `OrderedDict` and behave accordingly.

```
if isinstance(d, list):
    for item in d:
        if item["type"] == "a1":
            print(item["rel"])
elif isinstance(d, OrderedDict):
    if d["type"] == "a1":
        print(d["rel"])
```

The `TypeError` happens because when d is an OrderedDict rather than a list of OrderedDicts, the `for` loop iterates over the items in the OrderedDict, and those are strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply keep a flag that remembers if `item["type"] == "a1"` was ever true.

```
has_a1 = False
for item in d:
    if item["type"] == "a1":
        has_a1 = True
        print(item["rel"])
```

If you want the actual count, use an integer variable instead of a Boolean.

```
a1_count = 0
for item in d:
    if item["type"] == "a1":
        a1_count += 1
        print(item["rel"])
```

If you don't mind using more memory (and maybe there's a reason to do this anyway), keep a *list* of `item["rel"]` values instead of printing them on demand, then check the length of the list later.

```
a1_values = [item["rel"] for item in d if item["type"] == "a1"]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check that a key is present in a dictionary, without caring what specific value it has, use this:

```
if key in mydict:
```

So in your case, it would look like this:

```
if "type" in item:
    print(item["rel"])
```

Comment: That's not what is asked for. The question is not super clear, but it seems the key `type` is always there. OP is asking about when it has `a1` as the value